# MVC IPageList Paging showing two pager control

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new to MVC. I am trying to create a Grid structure based on some filters on page and then apply paging. Everything works fine except that when I click on second page, another pager control is added to page resulting in total two pager control on page. Any help would be highly appreciated. Below is my code:

Model:

```
public class UnMatched
{
    public List<string> List_BUnit { get; set; }
    public PagedList<UnMatched> List_Grid { get; set; }
 }
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? page)
{            

    return Request.IsAjaxRequest()
        ? (ActionResult)PartialView("AjaxMethod")
        : View(PopulateBUnit());
}

public ActionResult AjaxMethod(string bunit, int? Page)
{
   //Get lst_UnMatch here
   return PartialView(List_Grid.ToPagedList(pageIndex, pageSize));
}
```

Main View:

```
@model MVC_Sample.Models.UnMatched
@using PagedList;
@using PagedList.Mvc;
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
 }
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<div id="GridContainer" style="display:none;">
@Html.Partial("AjaxMethod", Model.List_Grid)
</div>
```

PartialView:

```
@model IPagedList<MVC_Sample.Models.UnMatched>
@using PagedList;
@using PagedList.Mvc;
<div id="GridDiv">
<table class="Grid">
<tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayName("rec_FSRPT_ID")
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayName("BUNit")
        </th>
</tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.rec_FSRPT_ID)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BUNit)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
</div>


</div>
<div id="myPager">
@Html.PagedListPager(
Model,
page => Url.Action("AjaxMethod", new { page = page}),
PagedListRenderOptions.EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing(new AjaxOptions(){  
HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "GridDiv" }))
</div>

<script>
$(function () {
$('#myPager').on('click', 'a', function () {
$.ajax({
url: this.href,
type: 'GET',
cache: false,
success: function (result) {
$('#myPager').html(result);
}
});
return false;
});
});
</script>
```

Pager Control screenshot:

[image: Pager Control screenshot]

Comment: I don't know if it's a typo, but your html elements doesn't close properly.

Comment: Thanks for checking. These were typo error and corrected now so if you could look into updated one and suggest.

Comment: What is the value of `this.href`? Looks like you are reloading the whole page within `#myPager`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for your help.

I put mypager div inside div Griddiv and it worked. On pager click, i was getting whole grid data again and then binding it to div #GridDiv.

```
<div id="GridDiv">
// grid.GetHTML code here
<div id="myPager">      

    @Html.PagedListPager(
    Model,
    page => Url.Action("AjaxMethod", new { page = page}),
    PagedListRenderOptions.EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing(new AjaxOptions(){ 
HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "GridDiv" }))
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of #myPager link click use the following code.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <div class="dataTables_info" id="dt_basic_info" role="status" aria-live="polite">Showing <span class="txt-color-darken">@Model.FirstItemOnPage</span> to <span class="txt-color-darken">@Model.LastItemOnPage</span> of <span class="text-primary">@Model.TotalItemCount</span> entries</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <a id="pagingFormAction" href="@Url.Action("AjaxMethod", new {  Pageindex = 1 bunit =  ViewBag.bunit })" style="display:none"></a>
        @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("AjaxMethod", new { Pageindex = page, bunit =  ViewBag.bunit }), PagedListRenderOptions.EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing(new PagedListRenderOptions() { ContainerDivClasses = new[] { "dataTables_paginate paging_simple_numbers" } }, new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "replace", UpdateTargetId = "GridDiv", OnBegin = "beginPaging", OnSuccess = "successPaging", OnFailure = "failurePaging" }))
    </div>
</div>
```

you can remove OnBegin = "beginPaging", OnSuccess = "successPaging", OnFailure = "failurePaging"  if not required.

Comment: I need to use ajax and not just a tag.